# Wso2am - Error in creating and login in tenants

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to create multiple tenants in a wso2am (1.10) installation.
When i create the tenant i get the following error "Failed to add tenant config" with the following exception

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-01 13:23:58,740] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.utils.TenantMgtUtil} -  Failed to add tenant config. tenant-domain: public.xxxxx, tenant-admin: admin. {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.utils.TenantMgtUtil}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not initialize class org.wso2.carbon.utils.i18n.Messages
```

Nevertheless when i try to enable the tenant it gets enabled and the required folders are created.
Unfortunately the tenants are not usable. On my first login i get the same exception

```
TID: [6] [] [2017-02-01 13:26:40,577] admin@remote.gunet [6] [AM]ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient} -  Error occurred while logging in {org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not initialize class org.wso2.carbon.utils.i18n.Messages
```

I have tried a clean installation of the server but that had no effect.
Is there some official guideline for the specific problem?

Comment: Post the entire exception trace.

Comment: Error in creating tenant 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vcfs9yflu6gqm5/error_create.txt


Error in login in

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4x5muotzdlw4316/error_login.txt

Comment: As per the logs there is some kind of keystore related error. But due to a error handling bug in 1.10.0, it does not show the exact error. This is fixed i 2.0.0. You should upgrade, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the keystore and the matter was resolved.